Lower Tail Bound for Noncentral chi-squared distribution
A noncentral chi-squared random variable $Z$ is of the form
$$
Z = \sum_{i=1}^k X_i^2
$$
where $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_i, \ldots, X_k)$ be $k$ are independent, normally distributed with mean $\mu_i$ and variance 1.
I am looking for a lower tail bound on $Z$, that is I would like to show that
$$
P(Z - \mathbb{E}[Z] < -t) \geq ce^{-c' t^2}
$$
where $c, c'>0$ are constants depending on $k$ and the non-centrality parameter $\lambda^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i^2$. Of course, this will require $0< t < \mathbb{E}[Z]$ or some similar condition. The most important criteria is getting $c'$ as large as possible.

The zero function works ;-).  Although trivial, this example raises the natural follow-up question: what do you need this bound for and how accurate does it need to be?  What form should it take--e.g., should it be computable in constant time, or amenable to analysis, etc.?  Please give us some guidance here.

Re the edit: because for large values of $t$ the variable $Z$ can be viewed as a small perturbation of a sum of squared Normals, which has a Gamma distribution, you can do much better than a Gaussian lower bound.  Intuitively--I have not done the analysis--you should expect to obtain a lower bound of the form $c,t^k\exp(-c^\prime t).$

You can obtain essentially the exact probability (at least exact to any desired precision) of the cdf of $Z$ and the desired probability using the Marcum Q function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcum_Q-function) so why do you need an upper bound?  (I'm not suggesting you don't have a reason.  I just don't see the need described in the question and putting that in might help you get an answer.)

@JimB  I'm working in an analytic context, so it would be helpful to have a convenient upper bound for the Marcum Q function/lower bound for the tail. In addition, most of the bounds on Wikipedia are for integer values of $\nu$, whereas for chi-square random variables we may encounter half-integer values,

Ok.  I see that your probability function no longer has the absolute value function and restricted the values of $t$ so I'll need to modify my answer.  I'll do that shortly.

The noncentrality parameter of the described non-central chisquared distribution will be the sum of squares of the means:  $\lambda^2=\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2+\cdots+\mu_k^2$ so if $ce^{-c' t^2}$ can be the form of a lower bound of
$$P(Z < \mathbb{E}[Z] - t)$$
for values $0<t<\mathbb{E}[Z]$, then $c$ and $c'$ would have to be functions of just $k$ and $\lambda^2$.  In other words, the individual means ($\mu_i$) can't be of any help determining $c$ and $c'$ given the sum of squares of the means.
We have $\mathbb{E}[Z]=k + \lambda^2$.
The desired probability can be determined essentially exactly in many programming languages.  Here is an implementation in R:
prob <- function(t, k, lambda2) {
  pchisq(k + lambda2 - t, k, lambda2)
}

k <- 5
lambda2 <- 10
EZ <- k + lambda2
t <- EZ*c(0:99)/100
p <- sapply(t, prob, k=k, lambda2=lambda2)
par(mai=c(1,1.5, 1, 0.5))
plot(sqrt(t), p, type="l", las=1, lwd=3, axes=FALSE,
  main=paste("k =", k, " and lambda2 =", lambda2), xlab="t", ylab="", log="y", font.lab=2)
par(xpd=TRUE)
text(-0.25*sqrt(EZ), 0.005, "Pr(Z < E(Z) - t)", srt=90, font=2)
par(xpd=FALSE)
axis(2, c(0.000001, 0.000005,0.00001, 0.0005, 0.0001, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.005,
  0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1), c("0.000001", "0.000005", "0.00001", "0.00005", 
  "0.0001", "0.0005", "0.001", "0.005", "0.01", "0.05", "0.1", "0.5", "1"), las=1)
axis(1, c(0:ceiling(EZ))^0.5, c(0:ceiling(EZ)))



The above curve shape is common for every combination of $k$ and $\lambda^2$ which given the square root scale for $t$ and the log scale for the probability isn't linear if an upper or lower bound of the form
$c e^{-c' t^2}$ is contemplated.
Using Mathematica the probability of interest is given by
Simplify[CDF[NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[k, lambda2], k + lambda2 - t], 
  Assumptions -> 0 < t < k + lambda2]//FunctionExpand
(* 1 - MarcumQ[k/2, Sqrt[lambda2], Sqrt[k + lambda2 - t]] *)

Using that function (or the one in R) gives (nearly) exact values.  The Wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcum_Q-function) has some series expansions and asymptotic forms.
